# Faster Tridiagonal Matrix Multiplication

Tags: performance, c, vectorization

I have a function that I've been trying to make faster that computes \$XA + B\$, where \$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}\$ is a tridiagonal matrix, and \$X, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}\$. In the code, the lower, main, and upper diagonals are represented by `dl, dm, du`. The naive implementation of this is,

```
/* Compute BA + X where A is tridiagonal shape (n, n), B, X are matrices shape (m, n) */
void dgtaxmt(const double *dl, const double *dm, const double *du,
             const double *x, const double *b, double *out,
             const unsigned int n, const unsigned int m, double *temp)
{
    int i, j, ii;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
        ii = i * n;
        temp[ii] = (x[ii] * dm[0]) + (x[ii + 1] * dl[0]) + b[ii];
        for (j = 1; j < n - 1; j++){
            temp[ii + j] = ((x[ii + j - 1] * du[j - 1]) + ((x[ii + j] * dm[j]) + ((x[ii + j + 1] * dl[j]) + b[ii + j])));
        }
        temp[ii + j] = (x[ii + j] * dm[j]) + (x[ii + j - 1] * du[j - 1]) + b[ii + j];
    }
    // store the transpose of temp into out
    // otrans(temp, out, m, n, 16);

}
```

Note that all of the pointers use the `restrict` keyword, but I left them out for readability. My attempts at increasing performance include tiling and using AVX intrinsics in hopes that not having to reload `dl, dm, du` would speed up the code, but it actually made it a lot slower. Is there anyway to vectorize this function in an efficient manner? Clang doesn't report any vectorization, and the assembly code it generates is using the xmm registers, but only the first value. Could there be a different order of operations that would allow better re-usage of data that's been previously loaded?

EDIT Here is the attempt I made with AVX intrinsics

```
void dgtaxmt_avx(const double *dl, const double *dm, const double *du,
                 const double *x, const double *b, double *out,
                 const unsigned int n, const unsigned int m, double *temp)
{
    // idx is for "rolling" values in vector to left by one index
    const __m256i idx = _mm256_set_epi32(1, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);
    __m256d dl_vec, dm_vec, du_vec, bn, xnm1, xn, xn1, tmp4;
    __m128d tmp2;

    unsigned int i, j, ii;
    const unsigned int r = ((n - 2) & (-4)) + 1;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
        ii = i * n;
        temp[ii] = (x[ii] * dm[0]) + (x[ii + 1] * dl[0]) + b[ii];
        for (j = 1; j < r; j += 4){
            dl_vec = _mm256_loadu_pd(&dl[j - 1]);
            dm_vec = _mm256_loadu_pd(&dm[j]);
            du_vec = _mm256_loadu_pd(&du[j]);
            bn     = _mm256_loadu_pd(&b[ii + j]);

            xnm1  = _mm256_loadu_pd(&x[ii + j - 1]);
            tmp2  = _mm_loadu_pd(&x[ii + j + 3]);
            xn1   = _mm256_set_m128d(tmp2, _mm256_extractf128_pd(xnm1, 1));

            // use permutations to avoid doing extra loads
            xn   = (__m256d)_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps((__m256)xnm1, idx);
            tmp4 = (__m256d)_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps((__m256)xn1,  idx);
            tmp2 = _mm256_extractf128_pd(tmp4, 0);
            xn   = _mm256_insertf128_pd(xn, tmp2, 1);

            tmp4 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(du_vec, xn1, bn);
            tmp4 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(dm_vec, xn, tmp4);
            tmp4 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(dl_vec, xnm1, tmp4);
            
            _mm256_storeu_pd(&out[ii + j], tmp4);
        }
        for (j = r; j < n - 1; j++){
            temp[ii + j] = ((x[ii + j - 1] * du[j - 1]) + ((x[ii + j] * dm[j]) + ((x[ii + j + 1] * dl[j]) + b[ii + j])));
        }
        temp[ii + j] = (x[ii + j] * dm[j]) + (x[ii + j - 1] * du[j - 1]) + b[ii + j];
    }
    
    otrans(temp, out, m, n, 16);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the attempted AVX code as well?

Comment: @harold I edited the question to include the AVX code. Sorry it's a littles messy since it was "experimental" code

Comment: I actually did not measure a serious performance issue in the AVX code. Are you running this on an AMD processor? `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` is a bigger problem for AMD

Comment: 1. How large are \$n\$ and \$m\$, and 2. Did you try computing the result column-wise (rather than row-wise)?

Comment: @harold I'm on a macbook running an intel i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz and I'm not entirely sure why I'm seeing the difference. In the intel documentation for broadwell, it says the efficiency of these instructions aren't too bad

Comment: @vnp My data is stored in row major form, so if I were to compute it column wise, wouldn't that cause a bunch of cache misses when accessing the data in `x`, and `b`? \$n, m\$ range from 100 to only 5000 since I have limited memory

Comment: That's exactly where I was driving to. I don't know the rest of your code, but exploring column-major layout _could_ be beneficial. And of course CUDA...

Comment: @vnp hmmm I hadn't thought of switching to column-major. It would be a lot of changes to convert everything over. Is there any immediate benefit to using column-major? I was always told that they are roughly the same in terms of performance.

Comment: The benefit I am thinking about is that you will naturally avoid reloading diagonals. A tricky part is that \$A\$ still needs to be row-major. Perhaps just transposing \$A\$ into column-major is a way to go. But as I said I don't know the rest of your code.

Comment: @vnp I'll give it a try. This code is apart of my personal library for numerically solving PDEs so I'll have to benchmark everything in order to really know if it provides any significant improvements